# "svn: E170001: Authentication required" when doing "gradlew :publish"

Tags: intershop

I am setting up an Intershop development environment on Mac OS X. "gradlew checkout" worked fine, also a direct "svn update" works. This means I am svn authenticated.

However, when calling "gradlew :publish" I get the message:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'a_responsive'.
    > svn: E170001: Authentication required for ...
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to depend on the operating system you're using and whether SVNKit is using the credentials stored in your user profile or not, but you can always fall back to either two properties or environment variables, whichever you prefer as described on the [scmversion-gradle-plugin github page](https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/scmversion-gradle-plugin#authentication).

In short: Either set the project property (via -P on the commandline or in gradle.properties) `scmUserName=<name>` and `scmUserPasswd=<password>` or set the environment variables `SCM_USERNAME=<name>` and `SCM_PASSWORD=<password>` to match your SVN login credentials.

Cheers!

Comment: I set user and password as environment variables. That worked just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the command line:

```
-Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,Negotiate,NTLM
```